# Как сделать обработчик события на продолжительное удерживание?

Tags: java, android

Есть

```
ListView lv;
```

и обработчик нажатия

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {...}
```

а как сделать обработчик на "удерживание", т.е. нажал и держишь секунду или две?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть у `ListView` соответствующий метод для задания обработчика "длинных" кликов.

```
void setOnItemLongClickListener (AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener listener)
```

Answer (score 0):

Регистрируете ваш `ListView` для контекстного меню, в методе `onCreate`

```
registerForContextMenu(lv);
```

И далее реализовываете метод обработки:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.lv) {
        ListView lv = (ListView) v;
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        Object obj = (Object) lv.getItemAtPosition(acmi.position);

        menu.add("One");
        menu.add("Two");
        menu.add("Three");
    }
}
```